# Retrieve data from SQL Server with AND/OR when some parameters may be left blank

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to retrieve data from SQL Server. The application allows the user to search by several parameters. There may be times when the user needs to leave one or more fields empty.

For example, they may search by last name, zip code, race; or they may search by last name and zip but not race; or they may search by zip and race only. You get the idea.

It's easy to do with only a few parameters. However, now I have a dozen parameters and it would take a long time to code each possible option separately.

Here is what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
    @LastName VARCHAR(50)
    @Zip NUMERIC(5)
    @Race VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE LastName = @LastName AND LastName != ''
       OR ZIP = @Zip AND ZIP != ''
       OR Race = @Race AND Race != ''
```

How could I use AND/OR at the same time?  This would get me the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Have a read of [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Reviting Catch-all Queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

Comment: Use parenthesis and even CASE statements. Put parentheses around your "AND" clauses, leaving the ORs outside, and you might have better luck.

Comment: Pay attention if your variable is null

Comment: **Note:** the datatype is `NUMERIC` - not "numberic" ...

Comment: Erland discusses this in exhaustive detail [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). And pay attention to the details. Why do you think you can pass an empty string as the value for your Race parameter? And do you understand what happens when you compare a numeric value to an empty string? Implicit conversions are generally not your ally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (LastName = @LastName AND LastName != '')
OR (ZIP =@Zip AND ZIP != '')
OR (Race = @Race AND Race != '')
```

This way, first the conditions in the parenthesis are executed and after that whole condition is tested.

But this query also has a bug. If the parameters @Lastname ='Smith', @ZIP=12345, @Race ='' then a record with LastName ='Doe', ZIP=12345 will also match .

I think

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (LastName = @LastName OR @LastName = '')
AND (ZIP =@Zip OR @Zip = '')
AND(Race = @Race OR @Race = '')
```

better suits your needs

Comment: `AND` already takes precedence over `OR` so that parenthesis won't change anything.

Comment: No. Parenthesis has the highest precedence.

Comment: You are right, that they have highest precedence but in the first expression (which was the only one before your edit and which my previous comment addressed) they don't change anything as the `AND` already has precedence over `OR`. There's no need to enforce a already given precedence with parenthesis.

Comment: The problem without parenthesis version is only one mismatch wolud cause a result with no results. The problem with the parenthesis but ORs are out was only matching one of three parameters should cause wrong matches.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is harder to write but much more efficient as OR condition in the WHERE causes several performance problems as is not SARGable:

```
DECLARE @LastName varchar (50) = 'LAST'
DECLARE @Zip NUMERIC (5) = 1
DECLARE @Race varchar (10)  = '1'

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @WHERE AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM myTable';
IF LEN(@LastName) > 0 
   SELECT @WHERE = @WHERE + 'LastName = ''' + @LastName + '''';

IF LEN(@Zip) > 0
   IF LEN(@WHERE) > 0
   SELECT @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND ZIP = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(18), @Zip) + '''';;
   ELSE
   SELECT @WHERE = 'ZIP = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(18), @Zip) ;

IF LEN(@Race) > 0
   IF LEN(@WHERE) > 0
       SELECT @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND Race = ''' + @Race + '''';
   ELSE
       SELECT @WHERE = 'Race = ''' + @Race + '''';
IF LEN(@WHERE) > 0 
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE ' + @WHERE 
-- PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parentheses

```
@LastName varchar (50)
@Zip numberic (5)
@Race varchar (10)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (LastName = @LastName AND LastName != '')
OR (ZIP =@Zip AND ZIP != '')
OR (Race = @Race AND Race != '')
```

When executing your query, code into parentheses is read with priority

Comment: `AND` already takes precedence over `OR` so that parenthesis won't change anything.

Comment: if you have doubts check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/parentheses-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017 where parentheses use is explained.

Comment: You may want to check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 (Level 6: `AND`, Level 7 `OR`)

Comment: Use parentheses to override the defined precedence of the operators in an expression. Everything within the parentheses is evaluated first to yield a single value before that value can be used by any operator outside the parentheses. this came from your link @stickybit

Comment: Again: There's no need to override the precedence as `AND` already has precedence over `OR`.

Comment: But when you have a mix between "and" & "or" you need parentheses, it does not harm performance and it makes the query more readable